# using resharper to extract a class and introduce a constructor dependency

Tags: refactoring, resharper, inversion-of-control, automated-refactoring, constructor-injection

Is it possible to use Resharper to refactor code such that the below method `Eat` is extracted into a seperate class, and the newly extracted class is injected in the `Dinner` class as an external dependency?

### Original Code

```
public class Dinner
{
    public Dinner()
    {

    }

    public void Eat()
    {
        //do the eating
    }
}
```

### Refactored Code

```
public interface IEatService
{
    void Eat();
}

public class EatService : IEatService
{
    public void Eat()
    {

    }
}
public class Dinner
{
    private readonly IEatService _eatService = null;

    public Dinner(IEatService eatService)
    {
        _eatService = eatService;
    }

    public void Eat()
    {
        _eatService.Eat();
    }

}
```

It doesn't have to be exactly as the refactored code - this is shown to give an idea.

Comment: Or if there is any tool that is able to do it, other than Resharper - I would be glad to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it nearly as you want in R# 7 using three-step refactoring:

1. Place the caret at your Eat method, invoke Extract Class refactoring (Ctrl-Shift-R in VS), name your class EatService.
2. Place the caret at your EatService class, invoke Extract Interface refactoring.
3. Place the caret at your EatService class, invoke Use Base type Where Possible refactoring.

All that is left is to fix a constructor in Dinner class so it would get IEatService as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Using R# 6, one way to achieve this would be with this sequence of operations. Note that refactorings are available on both `ReSharper | Refactor` on the menu bar, or (quicker) in context with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. There's still a bit of typing; I wouldn't be surprised if there were a way that didn't require you to type anything at all.

- Start with your Original Code in a file named `Dinner.cs`
- With the cursor on `Eat`, user the `Extract Interface` refactoring, naming the interface `IEatService`
- With the cursor on `IEatService`, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and create a derived type, accepting the offered name of `EatService`, and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to fill in the method implementation body
- Here's where we have to type: In `Dinner.Eat()`, type `_eatService.Eat();`. Note that `_eatService` is red; <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on it, choose 'Create field', change the offered type to `IEatService`
- With the cursor on the definition of `_eatService`, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and choose 'Initialize from ctor paramater, and then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> again and accept the `readonly` suggestion

Note that initialising `_eatService` to `null` is redundant; R# would let you know this.

We're now at your target code.

I think R# 7 has some new refactorings (such as Extract Class) which might make this quicker.